# trouble removing leaflet layers

Tags: layer, leaflet

I added a layer group to my map:

`L.layerGroup([marker1, marker2]).addTo(map);`

before however, i tried doing:
`var myLayer = L.layerGroup([marker1, marker2]);` 
but then I could never get it to add to the map

I want to remove the layergroup later on I've tried

```
  //map.removeLayer(LevelOneMarkers);

  //L.layerGroup([marker1, marker2]).removeLayer([marker1, marker2]);

  map.removeLayer([marker1, marker2]);
```

but non of those seem to work. am I missing something? I'm trying to follow

http://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were mostly there.

To create a series of markers and add it to a layerGroup and add that to the map:

```
var marker1 = new L.marker([51.5, -0.09]);
var marker2 = new L.marker([52, -0]);

var markers = L.layerGroup([marker1, marker2]);
map.addLayer(markers);
```

To remove that layerGroup from the map:

```
map.removeLayer(markers);  //this takes the name of the layerGroup as the argument
```

**References:**

[Leaflet API for LayerGroup](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layergroup)

[Bug fix so that removeLayer works on LayerGroups](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/issues/236)

**JSFiddle:** Here's a [working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MNy4F/).  Notice how it doesn't show anything because it removes the layerGroup AFTER adding it.  Comment out the removeLayer line to see the markers.